# How to Concat data using COALESCE in MySql

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

This is my SQL query

```
DECLARE @strManualRefundIdList AS VARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT  @strManualRefundIdList = COALESCE(@strManualRefundIdList + '|', '') + CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), ManualRefund_strReasonCode)
FROM tblManualRefunds WHERE ManualRefund_lngId IN ( 20 ,21 ,22 )

SELECT @strManualRefundIdList;
```

This gives like pivot, all the rows concatenated in a single row.
The Same i need to convert into MySql Query.

I tried like this

```
SELECT 
  CONCAT(COALESCE(CONCAT(v_strManualRefundIdList, '|'), '') , ( ManualRefund_lngId))                     
INTO 
  v_strManualRefundIdList 
FROM tblManualRefunds 
WHERE Trans_lngId IN ( 20 ,21 ,22 ) ;
```

But it throws error as `Error Code: 1172. Result consisted of more than one row`

How to translate that query. I am new to database.
Please help me in figuring out this.

**UPDATE :**

The way i found out was assigning into a cursor and loop through and concatenate it.
But is that the only way ? or any better way is available ?

Comment: Have you tried using [Group_Concat](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)?  This doesn't really seem like a pivot, more like an aggregate of rows.

Comment: @xQbert Thanks man.. I tried that now and it got working..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT group_concat(ManualRefund_strReasonCode SEPARATOR '|')
FROM tblManualRefunds
WHERE manualRefund_lngId in (20,21,22)
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/da6662/6/0)

Answer (score 0):

As per xQbert Comment i tried this

```
SELECT 
  GROUP_CONCAT(COALESCE(CONCAT('shan', '|'), '') , ( ManualRefund_lngId))                    
INTO 
  @v_strManualRefundIdList 
FROM tblManualRefunds ;
```

Its working fine.
Thanks Man.. !!!